# How to update system automatically on WiFi only?

Tags: software-updates

I would like to download (and install) updates for Linux Mint Cinnamone 18 x64 automatically (like MintUpdate), however, only when I am connected to WiFi. I frequently change source of Internet (USB/Bluetooth tether, different WiFi's) and manually start updates from time to time, as other sources than WiFi are usually from mobile Internet, that is both slow and expensive for updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also ping a unique IP (this might be tricky, you certainly have two network with 192.168.1.1 )

## arp solution

(this relay on mac adress)

I would use `neigh`(bour) option of `ip` utility.

from place where you want update to be done run

```
ip neigh
```

select the line with router IP put it in home.txt.

now update code will be.

```
if ip neigh | grep --quiet '"'$(< home.txt ) '"'
then
  update
fi
```

I would advise you to check update option, I am not sure this could be done (this is wise to do) unatended.